# Errors while compiling python package 'hyperopt'

Tags: python

Cloned the package `Hyperopt` from [Github](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-convnet).

Created a virtualenv, and ran the command `python setup.py install`

After successfully execution of the `setup.py`. When I ran the `THEANO_FLAGS=device=cpu shovel lfw.random_driver  --max_n_per_class=20`
to test whether the code has been installed properly or not. I was got the following errors.

```
No handlers could be found for logger "hpconvnet.utils"
/home/narak/Desktop/hyperopt-convnet/myhyper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.18.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
[ERROR] Failed to run task random_driver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/shovel/tasks.py", line 243, in __call__
    return self._obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/narak/Desktop/hyperopt-convnet/shovel/lfw.py", line 64, in random_driver
    space=search_space(bagging_fraction=1.0),
  File "/home/narak/Desktop/hyperopt-convnet/hpconvnet/lfw.py", line 92, in build_search_space
    'ctrl': hyperopt.Bandit.pyll_ctrl,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Bandit'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/narak/Desktop/hyperopt-convnet/myhyper/bin/shovel", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('shovel==0.3.0', 'shovel')
  File "/home/narak/Desktop/hyperopt-convnet/myhyper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 719, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/home/narak/Desktop/hyperopt-convnet/myhyper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1511, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/home/narak/Desktop/hyperopt-convnet/myhyper/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shovel-0.3.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/shovel", line 25, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/shovel/runner.py", line 119, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/shovel/tasks.py", line 246, in __call__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Bandit'
```

I checked whether `Bandit` has been installed or not. By doing `import bandit` it was successful.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Bandit'` does not try to import the module `bandit`. Instead it's trying to access the attribute `Bandit` of some module. Looking at the code in the repo, the first error you got was at [this line](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-convnet/blob/master/hpconvnet/lfw.py#L92).

Comment: You should have more luck if you post this as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-convnet/issues). Seems like there is a problem in the module itself, rather than python.